# how to use mapDispatchToProps in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am new in redux.

My code :

Home Screen

```
<Text> {{this.props.mycity}} </Text> 
const mapStateToProps = function(state) {
    return {
      mycity: state.layersFlag.baseDistrictADhabi //consist true/false 
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

Sidemenu Screen :
UI

```
<Switch onValueChange={(flag) => {
   this.props.toggleCity();
} value={this.state.city} /> 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        toggleCity: () => {
            dispatch({ type: "changeCity" })
        }
    };
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SideMenuScreen);
```

Store and reducer setup :

```
const initialState = {
    city : {
        mycity: true
    }
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "changeCity":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            mycity: action.payload.mycity
        })
    default:
        return state;
    }
}

const Store = createStore(reducer);
```

I am stuck in sidemenu. How to dispach in mapDispatchToProps method:

How to pass action in mapDispatchToProps in sidemenu?

Comment: Hmmm there's something strange about the structure of your code. You defined mapDispatchToProps() in your SideMenuScreen, but you want to call it inside your Switch component?

Comment: `How to pass action in mapDispatchToProps in sidemenu?` doesn't really make sense, you don't pass actions to that function. Do you mean how to pass values to one of the mapped functions? Like adding a payload to the `toggleCity` action?

Comment: I am stuck in dispatch method in  mapDispatchToProps?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo switch component in sidemenu screen

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari just wrote you an answer, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my assumptions on what your Switch component does is correct, it would trigger the `onValueChange` event-listener when you pass in `this.state.city` to the `value` prop. You end up calling `this.props.toggleCity()` to dispatch your changeCity action. I think the set-up is correct for here...

However, it looks like your reducer is expecting an `action.payload` which you never passed in as part of the action.

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "changeCity":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            mycity: action.payload.mycity
        })
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

So yes the dispatch is working correctly, but you are not passing all the necessary data for your reducer to return a new piece of state.

You need to update your `mapDispatchToProps`, your event-handler and your reducer to something like

```
<Switch onValueChange={(flag) => {
   this.props.toggleCity(this.state.city);
} value={this.state.city} /> 

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        toggleCity: (myCity) => {
            dispatch({ type: "changeCity", payload: myCity })
        }
    };
};
export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(SideMenuScreen);
```

Your reducer also seems to have an extra key, you don't need to access the mycity prop in payload if its already the payload. Update to:

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action)=>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "changeCity":
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            mycity: action.payload
        })
    default:
        return state;
    }
}
```

Adding on, if you want your Hone component to re-render with the new data in your redux-state, you can do something like this.

In your HomeScreen component, make use of a state-variable to save your abudhabi or whatever city-value and call componentDidUpdate() to setState and re-render your component.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component{
   state = {
      abudhabi: false
   }

//when the component gets the new redux state this will trigger
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
     if(this.props.abudhabi !== prevProps.abudhabi){
        this.setState({
           abudhabi: this.props.abudhabi 
       })
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari any luck on this? I'd be happy to help you debug if you got any errors.

Comment: yes right i didn't passing payload. now i am check how to pass payload correctly. thanks alot

Comment: now i am passing correct data to reducer and correctly assign but it is not reflecting in home screen.

Comment: Could you update the OP with your HomeScreen component. Since we've solved the redux part, I believe its just a matter of updating your component to make use of the new data.

Comment: initial state is correct. how to update it ? i thought it will automatically update home

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193445/discussion-between-christopher-ngo-and-khurshid-ansari).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance. finally resolve issue